# How to match "have", but not "had"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

I would like to match phrases like this:

- having the same issue
- facing the same problem
- have the same question
- I am getting the same issue
- I see the same issue
- I have same issue

But I do not want to match them if they are in the past tense, which means for example that anything containing the word had should be excluded:

- I had the same issue
- have had the same question

Later, I will add other words in past tense.

I tried this regex, but it still matches "the same issue" even if preceded by the word "had"

```
((?:i\s)?(?:have\s)?(?<!had\s)(?:(?:the\s|a\s)?same\s(?:(?:problem|question|issue)|here)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Nvjtqj/1

Why is this regex still finding phrase "same issue" even if it contains word "had" in front of it?

Comment: The `?` on your `(?:(?:the\s|a\s)` group allows the negative lookbehind to occur at `same` so for `had the same issue` it matches, but it won't match `had same issue` https://regex101.com/r/8vwOTI/1

Comment: @Nick That looks worthy to be down below (also).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think it's covered pretty well by oriberu answer

Comment: @Nick Yeah I saw it too and upvoted. I wonder why it was downvoted though. I thought it was well-explained. I had a comment about it but deleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to exclude all matches with the verb in Past tense you  want and then match what you need:

```
(\b(?:i\s+)?(?:have\s+)?)(?:had|faced)\s+((?:the\s+)?same\s+(?:problem|question|issue|here))(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)(?2)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x4Dip4/2)

**Details**

- `(\b(?:i\s+)?(?:have\s+)?)(?:had|faced)\s+((?:the\s+)?same\s+(?:problem|question|issue|here))(*SKIP)(*F)` - `(*SKIP)(*F)` will make the regex engine drop the text matched with the following patterns and go on looking for  a match at the failed location:

  - `(\b(?:i\s+)?(?:have\s+)?)` - Group 1:

    - `\b` - word boundary
    - `(?:i\s+)?` - an optional group matching an `i` and then 1+ whitespaces
    - `(?:have\s+)?` - an optional group matching a `have` and then 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:had|faced)` - `had` or `faced`
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `((?:the\s+)?same\s+(?:problem|question|issue|here))` - Group 2:

    - `(?:the\s+)?` -  an optional group matching a `the` and then 1+ whitespaces
    - `same\s+` - `same` and 1+ whitespaces
    - `(?:problem|question|issue|here)` - one of the words in the group
- `|` - or match and return the following match:

  - `(?1)` - Group 1 pattern repeated
  - `(?2)` - Group 2 pattern repeated

Comment: That's an interesting approach; I haven't seen recursion in a regex in ages and I don't think I have ever seen skip and fail. I learned something today, thanks. :)

Comment: This actually reminded me of an older pattern: `no|(yes)` where you match what you don't want and what you do want, but capture only the latter. Then you iterate over all matches but ignore those without captures. Very similar in spirit. ^^

Comment: This works if it is on its own. When I included this as part of my larger regex like so: `(<other capture>)|(<this regex>)|(<other capture>)` it doesn't work anymore. Is there any way to keep it as part of my large regex or do I need to execute regex for each pattern and then merge results together?

Comment: @Dharman If you have another regex, it is another question. Put all "exceptions" at the start of  regex. Adjust the recursion group IDs accordingly.

Comment: Not many of us know about those. Recommend you cite [How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex).

Answer (score 1):

When you don't anchor your lookarounds the regex engine will simply give up a word in order to make the expression match - 'the' in this case, since 'same' does not have the problem of being preceded by 'had'.

Note that this is stretching the limits of what you can and should do with one expression and entering the territory of multiple checks and parsers. If you need to do this with an expression, it could be something like:

```
^(?!.*\b(?:had)\b)(?=.*same (?:problem|question|issue)).*
```

where you make a positive and a negative assertion from the same fixed position.

Comment: This looked promising, but it is very greedy. I like the idea nonetheless.

Comment: @Dharman It is greedy and for this specific example I actually wouldn't have needed the positive lookahead; I think I mistakenly superimposed a different kind of problem there. The explanation preceeding the expression is valid, though. ;)